# Using Hibernate in Memory to cache web service results and run queries

Tags: web-services, hibernate, caching, in-memory-database

I'm considering caching web services results in a in-memory database (Hibernate) and run queries on the cache to perform some filtering and joins (on data from multiple web services.)

Is this a good idea (esp. from a performance point of view given that I've to return a response back to a client) ? Has anyone done something similar? Are there any other alternatives ?

Thanks.

Comment: Hibernate is not an in-memory database. It's an ORM. You may use Hibernate with an in-memory database, but you might also use an in-memory database without Hibernate.

Comment: I want to use HQL. What options do I've for in-memory databases ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-memory_database. AFAIK, Hibernate uses HSQLDB for its internal tests.